# What does $\epsilon_r$ represents in Coulomb's Law?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

Coulomb's Law is represented as $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$ (in vacuum)

In any other medium ,  $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}\epsilon_r}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$

My doubt is that , is this $\epsilon_r$ the  permitivity of the medium or the dielectric constant of the medium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\epsilon_{r}$ is the "relative permeability," which is more usually known as $\kappa$, the "dielectric constant."  The true permitivity is $\epsilon=\epsilon_{0}\epsilon_{r}$, which appears in the denominator of the in-medium force.

(Note that the expression for the in-medium force only holds in when both charges are embedded in a large block of uniform material.)

Comment: So that means  I can write $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}\epsilon_r}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$
as $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}k}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$
where k is dielectric constant . Also Can I write $F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$ where $\epsilon$  is the true permitiviity of the medium?

Comment: Yes, again with the proviso that that applies for the case in which both charges are embedded in a large block of uniform material.  Also, the dielectric constant is normally $\kappa$, not $k$.

Answer (score 4):

$\epsilon_r$ is the *relative* permittivity of the dielectric, also known as the *dielectric constant*. It is a number without units that tells you by what factor the dielectric reduces the force between charges (because of polarisation of the dielectric).

The role of $\epsilon_r$ is quite different from that of $\epsilon_0$, the *permittivity of free space* or *vacuum permittivity*. In the SI system of units, $\epsilon_0$ has units.

Sometimes you see the product $\epsilon_r \epsilon_0$ written as one lump, $\epsilon$, perhaps. This is sometimes just called the permittivity of the dielectric.

The slightly weird use and naming of these epsilons dates from the mid nineteenth century, before the electron was discovered and before Lorentz and others gave us our understanding of polarisation.